# Perl - Regexp to manipulate .csv

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I've got a function in Perl that reads the last modified .csv in a folder, and parses it's values into variables.

I'm finding some problems with the regular expressions.
My .csv look like:

```
Title is: "NAME_NAME_NAME"
"Period end","Duration","Sample","Corner","Line","PDP OUT TOTAL","PDP OUT OK","PDP OUT NOK","PDP OUT OK Rate"
"04/12/2014 11:00:00","3600","1","GPRS_OUT","ARG - NAME 1","536","536","0","100%"
"04/12/2014 11:00:00","3600","1","GPRS_OUT","USA - NAME 2","1850","1438","412","77.72%"
"04/12/2014 11:00:00","3600","1","GPRS_OUT","AUS - NAME 3","8","6","2","75%"


.(ignore this dot, you will understand later)
```

So far, I've had some help to parse the values into some variables, by:

```
open my $file, "<", $newest_file
        or die qq(Cannot open file "$newest_file" for reading.);
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {

    my ($date_time, $duration, $sample, $corner, $country_name, $pdp_in_total, $pdp_in_ok, $pdp_in_not_ok, $pdp_in_ok_rate) 
            = parse_line ',', 0, $line;

    my ($date, $time) = split /\s+/, $date_time;
    my ($country, $name) = $country_name =~ m/(.+) - (.*)/;

    print "$date, $time, $country, $name, $pdp_in_total, $pdp_in_ok_rate";
}
```

The problems are:

1. I don't know how to make the first AND second line (that are the column names from the .csv) to be ignored;
2. The file sometimes come with 2-5 empty lines in the end of the file, as I show in my sample (ignore the dot in the end of it, it doesn't exists in the file).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a CSV using Perl? Or are you trying to learn regexes w/Perl?

Comment: Actually, I'm doing both. I need to learn it, one way or another

Answer (score 3):

When you have a csv file with column headers and want to parse the data into variables, the simplest choice would be to use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). This code shows how you get your data into the hash reference `$row`. (I.e. `my %data = %$row`)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use feature 'say';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        binary  => 1,
        eol => $/,
    });
# open the file, I use the DATA internal file handle here
my $title = <DATA>;

# Set the headers using the header line
$csv->column_names( $csv->getline(*DATA) );

while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr(*DATA)) {
    # you can now access the variables via their header names, e.g.:
    if (defined $row->{Duration}) {  # this will skip the blank lines
        say $row->{Duration};
    }
}

__DATA__
Title is: "NAME_NAME_NAME"    
"Period end","Duration","Sample","Corner","Line","PDP IN TOTAL","PDP IN OK","PDP IN NOT OK","PDP IN OK Rate"
"04/12/2014 10:00:00","3600","1","GRPS_INB","CHN - Name 1","1198","1195","3","99.74%"
"04/12/2014 10:00:00","3600","1","GRPS_INB","ARG - Name 2","1198","1069","129","89.23%"
"04/12/2014 10:00:00","3600","1","GRPS_INB","NLD - Name 3","813","798","15","98.15%"
```

If we print one of the `$row` variables with `Data::Dumper`, it shows the structure we are getting back from `Text::CSV`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'PDP IN TOTAL' => '1198',
          'PDP IN NOT OK' => '3',
          'PDP IN OK' => '1195',
          'Period end' => '04/12/2014 10:00:00',
          'Line' => 'CHN - Name 1',
          'Duration' => '3600',
          'Sample' => '1',
          'PDP IN OK Rate' => '99.74%',
          'Corner' => 'GRPS_INB'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I don't know how to make the first line (that are the column names from the .csv) to be ignored;

```
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next  if $. == 1 || $. == 2;
```

> 2) The file sometimes come with 2-5 empty lines in the end of the file, as I show in my sample (ignore the dot in the end of it, it doesn't exists in the file).

```
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $. == 1 || $. == 2;
    next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
```

Comment: I missed the first real line, friend. Sorry. I edited the post

Comment: It still captures blank values... When I print, i receive balnk spaces into it :/

Comment: That should be `chomp $line;` and not just `chomp`. See the Perldoc on [chomp](http;//perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for more information. BTW, that perldoc.perl.org page is the complete documentation on Perl, and you can even select the version in the popup box on the top left to match your version.

Comment: I think you meant `\s*` and not `s*`

Answer (score 1):

```
open ...
my $names_from_first_line = <$file>; # you can use them or just ignore them

while($my line = <$file>) {
    unless ($line =~ /\S/) {
        # skip empty lines
        next;
    }
..
}
```

Also, consider using Text::CSV to handle CSV format

Comment: The OP is using `Text::ParseWords` which does a similar job to  `Text::CVS` does, but is a standard Perl module.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the valid lines will start with dates. I suggest you simply skip lines that don't start with dates in the format you expect:

```
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
    warn qq(next if not $line =~ /^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4}/;);  # Temp debugging line
    next if not $line =~ /^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4}/;
    warn qq($line matched regular expression);            # Temp debugging line
    ...
}
```

The `/^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4}",/` is a [regular expression pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). The pattern is between the `/.../`:

- `^` - Beginning of the line.
- `"` - Quotation Mark.
- `\d{2}` - Followed by two digits.
- `-` - Followed by a dash.
- `\d{2]` - Followed by two more digits.
- `-` - Followed by a dash.
- `\d{4}` - Followed by four more digits

This should be describing the first part of your line which is the date in `MM-DD-YYYY` format surrounded by quotes and followed by a comma. The `=~` tells Perl that you want the thing on the left to match the regular expression on the right.

Regular expressions can be difficult to understand, and is one of the reasons why Perl has such a reputation of being a *write-only* language. Regular expressions have been likened to *sailor cussing*. However, regular expressions is an extremely powerful tool, and worth the effort to learn. And with some experience, you'll be able to easily decode them.

The `next if...` syntax is similar to:

```
if (...) {
    next;
}
```

Normally, you shouldn't use post-fix `if` and never use `unless` (which is `if`'s opposite). They can make your program more difficult to understand. However, when placed right after the opening line of a loop like this, they make a clear statement that you're filtering out lines you don't want.  I could have written this (and many people would argue this is preferable):

```
 next unless $line =~ /^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4}",/;
```

This is saying you want to skip lines unless they match your regular expression. It's all a matter of personal preference and what do you think is easier for the poor schlub who comes along next year and has to figure out what your program is doing.

I actually thought about this and decided that `if not ...` was saying that I expect almost all lines in the file to match my format, and I want to toss away the few exceptions.  To me, `next unless ...` is saying that there are *some* lines that match my regular expression, and many lines that don't, and I want to only work on lines that match.

Which gets us to the next part of programming: Watching for things that will break your program. My previous answer didn't do a lot of error checking, but it should. What happens if a line doesn't match your format? What if the `split` didn't work? What if the fields are not what I expect? You should really check each statement to make sure it actually worked. Almost all functions in Perl will return a zero, a null string, or an undef if they don't work. For example, the `open` statement.

```
open my $file, "<", $newest_file
    or die qq(Cannot open file "$newest_file" for reading.);
```

If `open` doesn't work, it returns a file handle value of zero. The `or` states that if `open` doesn't return a non-zero file handle, execute the line that follows which kills your program.

So, look through your program, and see any place where you make an assumption that something works as expected and think what happens if it didn't. Then, add checks in your program to something if you get that exception. It could be that you want to report the error or log the error and skip to the next line. It could be that you want your program to come to a screeching halt. It could be that you can recover from the error and continue. What ever you do, check for possible errors (especially from *user input*) and handle possible errors.

---

#### Debugging

I told you regular expressions are tricky. Yes, I made a mistake assuming that your date was a separate field. Instead, it's followed by a space then the time which means that the final `",` in the regular expression should not be there. I've fixed the above code. However, you may still need to test and tweak. Which brings us into debugging in Perl.

You can use [warn](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) statements to help *debug* your program. If you copy a statement, then surround it with `warn qq(...);`, Perl will print out the line (filling out variables) and the line number. I even create macros in my various editors to do this for me.

The `qq(...)` is a [quote like operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators). It's another way to do double quotes around a string. The nice thing is that the string can contain actual quotation marks, and the `qq(...);` will still work.

Once you've finished debugging, you can search for your `warn` statements and delete them. Perl comes with a powerful [built in debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html), and many IDEs integrate with it. However, sometimes it's just easier to toss in a few `warn` statements to see what's going on in your code -- especially if you're having issues with regular expressions acting up.

Comment: Fella, what a beautiful answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: But I must say: When the program enters in the `while` loop, you make him wait for a date using this regular expression, but `/^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4}",/;` does not match the hour that follows after the YY, does it? When I run the program, it does not print nothing at all. I imagine it should be something like `/^"\d{2}-\d{2}-d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}",/;`, right?

Comment: Doesn't print anything that is inside the `while` loop*

Comment: Oh, that's right, there's no quotation mark or comma after the year. I was simply testing against the year because it would be enough to reject header lines or blank lines. I'll fix my post.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the regular expression. Plus, I added how you can use `warn` statements for debugging.